# Combining two lines at a time

Tags: ruby

I have a file that reads like this

```
2012-021    24X7 Online Tutoring Company    Applied 1/24/2012   Granted
506 S 4th St, Apt 308   Champaign   61820
Agarwal, Nikhil     506 S 4th st, Apt 308   Champaign   61820
2012-016    Corley Rentals  Applied 1/18/2012   Granted
1809 Philo Rd   Urbana  61802
Paynter, Barbara    1809 Philo Rd   Urbana  61802
Corley, Jim     1809 Philo Rd   Urbana  61802
```

I am attempting with Ruby to collect three lines at a time into an array and put them into a file as one line at a time. No matter what I do the lines will not output on the same line. They continue to be separate lines. I have tried to find new line characters and carriage return characters in each line but none exists. Can anyone tell me why these lines will not combine into one line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me.

```
DATA.lines.each_slice(3) { |lines| puts lines.map(&:chomp).join }
__END__
2012-021    24X7 Online Tutoring Company    Applied 1/24/2012   Granted
506 S 4th St, Apt 308   Champaign   61820
Agarwal, Nikhil     506 S 4th st, Apt 308   Champaign   61820
2012-016    Corley Rentals  Applied 1/18/2012   Granted
1809 Philo Rd   Urbana  61802
Paynter, Barbara    1809 Philo Rd   Urbana  61802
Corley, Jim     1809 Philo Rd   Urbana  61802
```

Answer (score 2):

Chomp!

Use the 'chomp' method to remove the trailing newlines that your input method is retaining.